# C# Check if string length is 188 if not

Tags: c#

After looking over @DanielBrughera code his method is what I needed thank you Daniel Brughera.

```
string inputtemplate = "00000000000000000000input0000000061306465643436000100000000000000input0000000000613064656434360001000000000000005bd0a47500000000000000000000000000000000";
string wordtoreplace = "input";
List<string> inputs = new List<string>() { "11antigeek11", "1antigeek11" };
foreach(string s in inputs)
{
int inputindex = inputtemplate.IndexOf(wordtoreplace);
if(inputindex < 0)
    Throw new Exception("Input not found");

string tmp;

if(s.Length < wordtoreplace.Length)
{
    tmp = String.Concat(s, new String('0', wordtoreplace.Length - s.Length));
}
else if(s.Length > wordtoreplace.Length)
{
    tmp = inputtemplate.Substring(inputindex, s.Length);
    if(tmp != String.Concat(wordtoreplace, new String('0', s.Length - wordtoreplace.Length)
        Throw new Exception("Input value is too long");
    else
        tmp = s;
}

inputtemplate = inputtemplate.Remove(inputindex, tmp.Length);
inputtemplate = inputtemplate.Insert(inputindex, tmp);
}
```

I would like to say thank you again Daniel Brughera.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for... just `if (input.Length == 188)`? It would be helpful if you'd give a more complete example (maybe with a shorter target length, e.g. 8 characters) as well as showing how far you've got so far.

Comment: Well you'd need `Length` rather than `length`... but yes, that's how you check the length of a string. It's still unclear to me what you're asking. Please edit your question with a complete example. (And as I say, even if your *real* requirement is a length of 188, the example would be simpler to understand with a length of 8 or something else that's nice and short.)

Comment: Okay the rest of the string stay the same other then the input and the 00000000 after the inputs what I'm needing is when I put those words into the input and if the string length is more or less then 188 it will either remove or add to the 00000000 after the input until it gets to the length of the string which is 188

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Please *edit the question* (instead of just adding comments) and give a concrete example, with the code you've got so far.

Comment: Improve the question because it is not easy to understand what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way you will always get the same length as inputtemplate, in case you need to use the editable spaces (0's), I included a validation to prevent overwrite other values...

```
string inputtemplate = "00000000000000000000input0000000061306465643436000100000000000000input0000000000613064656434360001000000000000005bd0a47500000000000000000000000000000000";
string wordtoreplace = "input";
List<string> inputs = new List<string>() { "11antigeek11", "1antigeek11" };
foreach(string s in inputs)
{
    int inputindex = inputtemplate.IndexOf(wordtoreplace);
    if(inputindex < 0)
        Throw new Exception("Input not found");

    string tmp;

    if(s.Length < wordtoreplace.Length)
    {
        tmp = String.Concat(s, new String('0', wordtoreplace.Length - s.Length));
    }
    else if(s.Length > wordtoreplace.Length)
    {
        tmp = inputtemplate.Substring(inputindex, s.Length);
        if(tmp != String.Concat(wordtoreplace, new String('0', s.Length - wordtoreplace.Length)
            Throw new Exception("Input value is too long");
        else
            tmp = s;
    }

    inputtemplate = inputtemplate.Remove(inputindex, tmp.Length);
    inputtemplate = inputtemplate.Insert(inputindex, tmp);
}
```

Comment: No, I did do that but it change the last part of the string so it wouldn't work. After looking at the original string I have to change the string after the input data

Comment: an example would be nice

Comment: That's a [Schlemiel The Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm), though. There are better ways of pasting the correct amount of zeroes behind it in a single operation.

Comment: I'm trying to think how I would make a example

Comment: an straight forward input => desired output example is enough

Comment: @antigeek: Or potentially multiple *different* inputs with desired outputs. But again, I wouldn't expect the examples to *actually* need 188 characters. Work out what you'd do if you only needed (say) 8 or 16 characters. That will make for *much* simpler examples, but any answer that applies to the short case will work for the longer case too.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBrughera it worked That's what I needed.